# Text cropped on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: bug, design

As you can see on the the following screenshot a posting which contains code is cropped on the right side of the display on a windows phone 8.1 device. You even cannot scroll to see the full text.

Screenshot posting: [Website Projects in Azure Web Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098988/website-projects-in-azure-web-role)

[image]

Comment: The Windows Phone browser is [not a supported browser](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).

Comment: Nonsense! Exactly your link says Mobile View > Internet Explorer Mobile > Works with Windows Phone 8, at least.

Comment: Note that it is not bolded; the list is community curated, it means someone found it to be working. I doubt the team will actively pursue making the mobile web version work without glitches such as you have found.

Comment: @MartijnPieters WP 8.1 runs IE 11

Comment: @Stijn: it runs *mobile* IE11 then. :-)

Comment: @Stijn: and I was responding to an older revision of the comment.

Comment: Anyway, regardless of what browser it runs, if we're not getting an app anytime soon it would be nice if the mobile website works properly :)

Answer (score 1):

The <blockquote/> element seems to be the culprit. If you add the following css property to the blockquote the content of the blockquote will be broken correctly:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```